# How to Show Path Connectedness of Double Cone

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

I am asked to show that the set $C=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2+y^2=z^2\}$ is path connected.

Visually this makes sense to me given that the cones share the point $(0,0,0)$ which provides me with a way to get from any point on the top cone to the bottom cone via a continuous path.

My thoughts so far: I think the single cone with $(0,0,0)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$, as we can just project any $(x,y,z)\in C$ straight downward onto  the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is  path-connected, which would tell me that each cone is path-connected given that path-connectedness is a topological invariant. Since the union of path-connected sets sharing a common point is path-connected, so  is $C$.

My problem is that we were suggested to try the problem in the textbook immediately after being given that every open connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$ is path connected, and also given the following information:

(1) $\mathbb{R}$ is connected

(2) Connectedness is a topological invariant

(3) The union of connected sets sharing a common point is connected

(4) All connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are path-connected

My professor is a huge fan of really slick proofs, and given that the general idea my proof (assuming that it is correct) uses a lot of information which has not yet been given to us, I'm thinking there is some really nice way to go about this that I am missing.

So is there a more elementary method of showing this that someone can give me a hint as to how to go about doing?  (please do not give a full answer, only hints).

Comment: You can provide a very basic proof by exhibiting an explicit path that connects any point of the cone with the origin. (You can actually prove that the set is "star-shaped", which is more than path connected)

Comment: Was my reasoning sound in the handwavy proof I gave?

Comment: Yes, but you said too many useless things. Just show an equation, it is more than enough (IMHO).

Comment: I knew there was a slick way to do this. Thanks for the hint :).

Comment: I mean, I expect a proof to be like that: "let $x$ be a point on the cone. Then the path $\ldots$ connects $x$ to $0$. (explain why). Since all points of the cone can be path-connected with the origin, the cone itself is path connected (this is obvious enough to be stated without proof IMHO)".

Comment: Yes I understood after the first hint. Thank you.